# Присваивание в цикле значений нескольким переменным

Tags: python, циклы

Чувствую, что вопрос решаем в 1 строку, но никак не дойдёт до меня это решение. Есть цикл. Есть две переменные, скажем, a и b. Если, при итерации по списку мы встречаем число, присваиваем его переменной а, идем дальше, если снова число, то кладем его уже в переменную b. Как реализовать такое на python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как вариант - добавить счетчик и если он четный - класть в `a`, иначе - в `b`

```
if is_number():
    counter += 1
    if counter % 2 == 0:
        a = value
    else
        b = value
```

не в 1 строчку, но в лоб :)

можно конечно и в пару строчек

```
counter += 1
a, b = value if counter % 2 else a, value if not counter % 2 else b
```

Answer (score 1):

`a, b = (k, b) if a == None else (a, k)`

`a` еще пустое или нет? Сработает как `a, b = (k, b)` или `a, b = (a, k)` в зависимости от результата проверки.

```
a = None
b = None

for k in ["a", 4, "b", 7, True]:
  if type(k) == int:
    a, b = (k, b) if a == None else (a, k)

print( a, b ) # 4, 7
```

Но так просто не надо делать!) Потому что напрашивается вопрос: что, если чисел будет 3 или 17 штук? Для такой задачи существует массив.

```
arr = []

for k in ["a", 4, "b", 7, True, 17]:
  if type(k) == int: arr.append(k)

print( arr ) # [4, 7, 17]
print( arr[0] ) # 4
print( arr[1] ) # 7
print( arr[2] ) # 17
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно и в одну строчку.

```
data = ['q', 'w', 5, 'e', 'r', 7, 't', 'y', 9]

a, b, *rest = [x for x in data if isinstance(x, int)]

print(a, b)
```

Но работает только для чисел конкретного типа (в данном случае int), и только если в списке гарантировано есть по крайней мере два числа.

Если нужно сделать так, чтобы код не падал для случая, когда в списке меньше двух чисел, то можно дописать строчку так:

```
a, b, *rest = [x for x in data if isinstance(x, int)] + [None, None]
```